# Disabling IRQ #16 and *BAD*gran_size

Tags: mouse, 13.04

I upgrade to Ubuntu 13.04 and some times appears in boot display a message:

```
Disabling IRQ #16
```

When this message appears, I must reboot because the mouse turns very slow and doesn't response correctly.
I suppose that is a IRQ Conflict problem, but how I can resolve it?

```
SO: 3.8.0-19-generic #29-Ubuntu SMP Wed Apr 17 18:16:28 UTC 2013 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
Motherboard: GA-H77M-D3H
Ethernet: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8169 PCI Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 10)
```

NEWs:

I removed RTL8169 external ethernet to simplify error possibilities. Without this card, I had tested different BIOS configurations and the result is:

1. Disabling IRQ #16 appears when I enable "**Intel Virtualization Technology**" in the bios.
2. When I disable the integrated ethernet in the BIOS, motherboard is freeze in the reboot, when show Gigabyte's logo. I must remove battery for two minutes to restore the BIOS.

**Other possible symptom i found in dmesg output:**

A lot of entries with this patter:

```
*BAD*gran_size: 64K     chunk_size: 16M     num_reg: 10     lose cover RAM: -8M 
...........
...........
```

A lot of entries with this pattern:

```
[    0.000000] total RAM covered: 16302M
[    0.000000]  gran_size: 64K  chunk_size: 64K     num_reg: 10     lose cover RAM: 246M
[    0.000000]  gran_size: 64K  chunk_size: 128K    num_reg: 10     lose cover RAM: 246M
[    0.000000]  gran_size: 64K  chunk_size: 256K    num_reg: 10     lose cover RAM: 246M
[    0.000000]  gran_size: 64K  chunk_size: 512K    num_reg: 10     lose cover RAM: 246M
[    0.000000]  gran_size: 64K  chunk_size: 1M  num_reg: 10     lose cover RAM: 246M
[    0.000000]  gran_size: 64K  chunk_size: 2M  num_reg: 10     lose cover RAM: 246M
[    0.000000]  gran_size: 64K  chunk_size: 4M  num_reg: 10     lose cover RAM: 246M
[    0.000000]  gran_size: 64K  chunk_size: 8M  num_reg: 10     lose cover RAM: 246M
[    0.000000] *BAD*gran_size: 64K  chunk_size: 16M     num_reg: 10     lose cover RAM: -8M
[    0.000000] *BAD*gran_size: 64K  chunk_size: 32M     num_reg: 10     lose cover RAM: -8M
[    0.000000] *BAD*gran_size: 64K  chunk_size: 64M     num_reg: 10     lose cover RAM: -8M
[    0.000000]  gran_size: 64K  chunk_size: 128M    num_reg: 10     lose cover RAM: 0G
...........
...........
```

Other possible error:

```
[   18.518043] ACPI Warning: 0x0000000000000428-0x000000000000042f SystemIO conflicts with Region \PMIO 1 (20121018/utaddress-251)
[   18.518048] ACPI: If an ACPI driver is available for this device, you should use it instead of the native driver
[   18.518051] ACPI Warning: 0x0000000000000530-0x000000000000053f SystemIO conflicts with Region \GPIO 1 (20121018/utaddress-251)
[   18.518054] ACPI: If an ACPI driver is available for this device, you should use it instead of the native driver
[   18.518056] ACPI Warning: 0x0000000000000500-0x000000000000052f SystemIO conflicts with Region \LED_ 1 (20121018/utaddress-251)
[   18.518076] ACPI Warning: 0x0000000000000500-0x000000000000052f SystemIO conflicts with Region \GPIO 2 (20121018/utaddress-251)
[   18.518079] ACPI: If an ACPI driver is available for this device, you should use it instead of the native driver
[   18.518080] lpc_ich: Resource conflict(s) found affecting gpio_ich
```

**Trace how disable IRQ16:**

```
[    0.907977] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Attached SCSI disk
[    0.936700] usb 1-1: New USB device found, idVendor=8087, idProduct=0024
[    0.936701] usb 1-1: New USB device strings: Mfr=0, Product=0, SerialNumber=0
[    0.936813] hub 1-1:1.0: USB hub found
[    0.936841] hub 1-1:1.0: 6 ports detected
[    1.048329] usb 2-1: new high-speed USB device number 2 using ehci-pci
[    1.062340] irq 16: nobody cared (try booting with the "irqpoll" option)
[    1.062342] Pid: 0, comm: swapper/4 Tainted: GF            3.8.0-19-generic #29-Ubuntu
[    1.062343] Call Trace:
[    1.062344]  <IRQ>  [<ffffffff810ecbcd>] __report_bad_irq+0x3d/0xe0
[    1.062350]  [<ffffffff810ed092>] note_interrupt+0x1c2/0x210
[    1.062353]  [<ffffffff815735bb>] ? cpuidle_wrap_enter+0x5b/0xa0
[    1.062354]  [<ffffffff81572b70>] ? centrino_target+0x370/0x370
[    1.062356]  [<ffffffff810ea807>] handle_irq_event_percpu+0xa7/0x1f0
[    1.062357]  [<ffffffff81572b70>] ? centrino_target+0x370/0x370
[    1.062359]  [<ffffffff810ea99e>] handle_irq_event+0x4e/0x80
[    1.062360]  [<ffffffff810edbda>] handle_fasteoi_irq+0x5a/0x100
[    1.062363]  [<ffffffff810164ce>] handle_irq+0x1e/0x30
[    1.062366]  [<ffffffff816d54aa>] do_IRQ+0x5a/0xe0
[    1.062367]  [<ffffffff816cb4ad>] common_interrupt+0x6d/0x6d
[    1.062368]  <EOI>  [<ffffffff815735bb>] ? cpuidle_wrap_enter+0x5b/0xa0
[    1.062370]  [<ffffffff81573610>] cpuidle_enter_tk+0x10/0x20
[    1.062372]  [<ffffffff81573205>] cpuidle_idle_call+0xa5/0x260
[    1.062374]  [<ffffffff8101d5af>] cpu_idle+0xaf/0x120
[    1.062377]  [<ffffffff816b4e0e>] start_secondary+0x1e0/0x1e5
[    1.062377] handlers:
[    1.062380] [<ffffffff814f8cb0>] usb_hcd_irq
[    1.062381] Disabling IRQ #16
```

**And this is content of /proc/interrupts**

When IRQ16 is NO disabled:

```
           CPU0       CPU1       CPU2       CPU3       CPU4       CPU5       CPU6       CPU7       
  0:         43          0          0          0          0          0          0          0  IR-IO-APIC-edge      timer
  1:          2          0          0          0          0          0          0          0  IR-IO-APIC-edge      i8042
  7:          0          0          0          0          0          0          0          0  IR-IO-APIC-edge      parport0
  8:          0          0          0          0          1          0          0          0  IR-IO-APIC-edge      rtc0
  9:          0          0          0          0          0          0          0          0  IR-IO-APIC-fasteoi   acpi
 12:          3          0          0          0          1          0          0          0  IR-IO-APIC-edge      i8042
 16:       1986         36        308       8342        226         56       8481     154948  IR-IO-APIC-fasteoi   ehci_hcd:usb1
 18:         59      63470         12         29         42      68182         24         31  IR-IO-APIC-fasteoi   eth1
 23:       3724       2201         59       1529      74045      49806        453      19695  IR-IO-APIC-fasteoi   ehci_hcd:usb2
 40:          0          0          0          0          0          0          0          0  DMAR_MSI-edge      dmar0
 41:          0          0          0          0          0          0          0          0  DMAR_MSI-edge      dmar1
 42:          0          0          0          0          0          0          0          0  IR-PCI-MSI-edge      xhci_hcd
 43:       8436       7375       4020       4555       8608      28721      20001      20889  IR-PCI-MSI-edge      ahci
 44:          9          1          0          0          0          4          1          0  IR-PCI-MSI-edge      mei
 45:     625228      20562      17848      17739      58665      42944      36267      32186  IR-PCI-MSI-edge      i915
 46:        159          4          6          6        523        121          1          8  IR-PCI-MSI-edge      snd_hda_intel
 47:          0          0          0          0          0          0          0          0  IR-PCI-MSI-edge      eth0
 48:          0          0          0          0          0          0          0          0  IR-PCI-MSI-edge      eth0-TR-0
 49:          0          0          0          0          0          0          0          0  IR-PCI-MSI-edge      eth0-TR-1
 50:          0          0          0          0          0          0          0          0  IR-PCI-MSI-edge      eth0-TR-2
 51:          0          0          0          0          0          0          0          0  IR-PCI-MSI-edge      eth0-TR-3
 52:          0          0          0          0          0          0          0          0  IR-PCI-MSI-edge      eth0-R-4
 53:          0          0          0          0          0          0          0          0  IR-PCI-MSI-edge      eth0-R-5
 54:          0          0          0          0          0          0          0          0  IR-PCI-MSI-edge      eth0-R-6
 55:          0          0          0          0          0          0          0          0  IR-PCI-MSI-edge      eth0-R-7
NMI:        874        766        742        713        293        316        324        345   Non-maskable interrupts
LOC:     759575     759342     748379     849342     210905     248734     229921     283703   Local timer interrupts
SPU:          0          0          0          0          0          0          0          0   Spurious interrupts
PMI:        874        766        742        713        293        316        324        345   Performance monitoring interrupts
IWI:          0          0          0          0          0          0          0          0   IRQ work interrupts
RTR:          0          0          0          0          0          0          0          0   APIC ICR read retries
RES:     295355      94827       9724      31512       2742       2897       2222       6768   Rescheduling interrupts
CAL:        508        543        499        543        522        540        515        515   Function call interrupts
TLB:      21058      21800      15397      13086       7965       8805       8672       6416   TLB shootdowns
TRM:          0          0          0          0          0          0          0          0   Thermal event interrupts
THR:          0          0          0          0          0          0          0          0   Threshold APIC interrupts
MCE:          0          0          0          0          0          0          0          0   Machine check exceptions
MCP:         38         38         38         38         38         38         38         38   Machine check polls
ERR:          0
MIS:          0
```

When IRQ16 is disabled and mouse doesn't response correctly:

```
          CPU0       CPU1       CPU2       CPU3       CPU4       CPU5       CPU6       CPU7       
  0:         43          0          0          0          0          0          0          0  IR-IO-APIC-edge      timer
  1:          0          0          1          0          1          0          0          0  IR-IO-APIC-edge      i8042
  7:          0          0          0          0          0          0          0          0  IR-IO-APIC-edge      parport0
  8:          0          1          0          0          0          0          0          0  IR-IO-APIC-edge      rtc0
  9:          0          0          0          0          0          0          0          0  IR-IO-APIC-fasteoi   acpi
 12:          2          0          0          0          0          1          0          1  IR-IO-APIC-edge      i8042
 16:      11008        789        530        240      43614      25676      17062       1082  IR-IO-APIC-fasteoi   ehci_hcd:usb1
 18:       1803          4          6         22       2077          8         20         23  IR-IO-APIC-fasteoi   eth1
 23:        207         30          4         16        276        942         34         10  IR-IO-APIC-fasteoi   ehci_hcd:usb2
 40:          0          0          0          0          0          0          0          0  DMAR_MSI-edge      dmar0
 41:          0          0          0          0          0          0          0          0  DMAR_MSI-edge      dmar1
 42:          0          0          0          0          0          0          0          0  IR-PCI-MSI-edge      xhci_hcd
 43:       7502        297       1784         50       1049       1504       9829         57  IR-PCI-MSI-edge      ahci
 44:          5          0          0          0          8          2          0          0  IR-PCI-MSI-edge      mei
 45:       6015        127        371         58        366        170        575        140  IR-PCI-MSI-edge      i915
 46:        134         20          4          3        185        454         23          9  IR-PCI-MSI-edge      snd_hda_intel
 47:          0          0          0          0          0          0          0          0  IR-PCI-MSI-edge      eth0
 48:          0          0          0          0          0          0          0          0  IR-PCI-MSI-edge      eth0-TR-0
 49:          0          0          0          0          0          0          0          0  IR-PCI-MSI-edge      eth0-TR-1
 50:          0          0          0          0          0          0          0          0  IR-PCI-MSI-edge      eth0-TR-2
 51:          0          0          0          0          0          0          0          0  IR-PCI-MSI-edge      eth0-TR-3
 52:          0          0          0          0          0          0          0          0  IR-PCI-MSI-edge      eth0-R-4
 53:          0          0          0          0          0          0          0          0  IR-PCI-MSI-edge      eth0-R-5
 54:          0          0          0          0          0          0          0          0  IR-PCI-MSI-edge      eth0-R-6
 55:          0          0          0          0          0          0          0          0  IR-PCI-MSI-edge      eth0-R-7
NMI:          7          4          4          4          6          3          9          1   Non-maskable interrupts
LOC:       9814       7028       5981       6435       7513       4103       9617       3359   Local timer interrupts
SPU:          0          0          0          0          0          0          0          0   Spurious interrupts
PMI:          7          4          4          4          6          3          9          1   Performance monitoring interrupts
IWI:          0          0          0          0          0          0          0          0   IRQ work interrupts
RTR:          0          0          0          0          0          0          0          0   APIC ICR read retries
RES:       2780       1082        426        299        290        258        308        189   Rescheduling interrupts
CAL:        539        533        548        566        447        560        547        552   Function call interrupts
TLB:        551        438        367        491        368        553       1703        291   TLB shootdowns
TRM:          0          0          0          0          0          0          0          0   Thermal event interrupts
THR:          0          0          0          0          0          0          0          0   Threshold APIC interrupts
MCE:          0          0          0          0          0          0          0          0   Machine check exceptions
MCP:          2          2          2          2          2          2          2          2   Machine check polls
```

When IRQ16 is disabled and mouse responses correctly (a new status):

```
           CPU0       CPU1       CPU2       CPU3       CPU4       CPU5       CPU6       CPU7       
  0:         22          0          0          0          0          0          0          0  IR-IO-APIC-edge      timer
  1:          1          0          0          0          0          1          0          0  IR-IO-APIC-edge      i8042
  7:          0          0          0          0          0          0          0          0  IR-IO-APIC-edge      parport0
  8:          1          0          0          0          0          0          0          0  IR-IO-APIC-edge      rtc0
  9:          0          0          0          0          0          0          0          0  IR-IO-APIC-fasteoi   acpi
 12:          2          0          0          0          1          0          0          1  IR-IO-APIC-edge      i8042
 16:      44189         20          7          2      44042      10916        697        128  IR-IO-APIC-fasteoi   ehci_hcd:usb1
 18:         69          4         11          8        107         20         14         14  IR-IO-APIC-fasteoi   eth1
 19:       5264        244        939         75        539        567       2995        149  IR-IO-APIC-fasteoi   ata_piix, ata_piix
 23:        340         32          7          2        305       2821         17         13  IR-IO-APIC-fasteoi   ehci_hcd:usb2
 40:          0          0          0          0          0          0          0          0  DMAR_MSI-edge      dmar0
 41:          0          0          0          0          0          0          0          0  DMAR_MSI-edge      dmar1
 42:         14          0        157         14          1          3        698        283  IR-PCI-MSI-edge      xhci_hcd
 43:          9          0          2          0          0          0          4          0  IR-PCI-MSI-edge      mei
 44:        621        119        226         72        101        141        619        116  IR-PCI-MSI-edge      i915
 45:         62         15        152          1        362        143         54         43  IR-PCI-MSI-edge      snd_hda_intel
 46:          0          0          0          0          0          0          0          0  IR-PCI-MSI-edge      eth0
 47:          0          0          0          0          0          0          0          0  IR-PCI-MSI-edge      eth0-TR-0
 48:          0          0          0          0          0          0          0          0  IR-PCI-MSI-edge      eth0-TR-1
 49:          0          0          0          0          0          0          0          0  IR-PCI-MSI-edge      eth0-TR-2
 50:          0          0          0          0          0          0          0          0  IR-PCI-MSI-edge      eth0-TR-3
 51:          0          0          0          0          0          0          0          0  IR-PCI-MSI-edge      eth0-R-4
 52:          0          0          0          0          0          0          0          0  IR-PCI-MSI-edge      eth0-R-5
 53:          0          0          0          0          0          0          0          0  IR-PCI-MSI-edge      eth0-R-6
 54:          0          0          0          0          0          0          0          0  IR-PCI-MSI-edge      eth0-R-7
NMI:          7          5          3          3          3          1          3          2   Non-maskable interrupts
LOC:       9085       7261       6749       6803       9853       5303       7399       4982   Local timer interrupts
SPU:          0          0          0          0          0          0          0          0   Spurious interrupts
PMI:          7          5          3          3          3          1          3          2   Performance monitoring interrupts
IWI:          0          0          0          0          0          0          0          0   IRQ work interrupts
RTR:          0          0          0          0          0          0          0          0   APIC ICR read retries
RES:       1791        870        339        303        245        217        350        211   Rescheduling interrupts
CAL:        489        487        559        563        490        536        567        488   Function call interrupts
TLB:        435        277        544        370        320        301        685        316   TLB shootdowns
TRM:          0          0          0          0          0          0          0          0   Thermal event interrupts
THR:          0          0          0          0          0          0          0          0   Threshold APIC interrupts
MCE:          0          0          0          0          0          0          0          0   Machine check exceptions
MCP:          2          2          2          2          2          2          2          2   Machine check polls
```

News:
I tested with latest BIOs. Error persists, but minus errors appears in dmesg. For example, *BAD*gran_size has been disappear.
A curiosity: Firmwares files in GIGAByte web are .exe !!!! and the last BIOS image is 10 months old **beta** version!

Comment: Add the contents of /proc/interrupts to your question.

Comment: @psusi I add new information. /proc/interrupts and dmesg output

Comment: Sounds like a buggy bios; check if there's an update.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Definitive solution: Replace Gigabyte GA-H77M-D3H with an Asus P8H77-M

Comment: just for general information , did you tried to update your BIOS ?

Comment: @Qasim Yes, I tested with various BIOS. You can read the end of the question.